# True-Time debugger / hiwave.exe: run multiple instances?

Tags: debugging, embedded, microcontroller, 68hc11

I have a couple Freescale 68HCS08 MCUs connected in an I2C network, running different programs. When I click "debug," Codewarrior checks for a running instance of `hiwave.exe` to load and debug the program. I'd like to debug both simultaneously, which means having two instances running.

What is the best way to do this? Do I need two PC's? Is it better to try and manually reload the MCU's, using the Build command instead of Debug in Codewarrior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can run two instances of hiwave.exe manually, and then use the "File"->"Load Application" menu item to select the .abs file.  It seems to run both instances fine, including code display and breakpoints, although I'm using full-chip simulation rather than a hardware debugger at the moment.  I would guess that's where most of the fun is, in making sure that each instance uses the correct debugger, especially if you're using two of the same USB devices.

"That's too easy", I can hear you saying.  Fine, take option 2:

I do all my CodeWarrior / Hiwave stuff in "Windows XP Mode", a Virtual PC running under Windows 7, mostly because CodeWarrior's installer doesn't run on 64-bit architectures (or it didn't a few months ago, for which I yelled at them in their forums).

I'm not entirely sure of the licensing technicalities (if you have Windows 7 pro, you should get at least one free license to use the Windows XP mode), but perhaps you could do something similar - e.g. run a Virtual PC environment with one of your debuggers passed through to the virtual system (Windows Virtual PC and other virtualization environments let you pass USB devices through), and have your other debugger still attached to the 'host' system.  You could then have CodeWarrior/Hiwave installed on both the virtual and host systems, with one controlling system A and the other controlling system B.  USB fun-time still applies, as you'd have to make sure the 'correct' USB debugger was passed through to the virtual system.

Answer (score 1):

The debugger, HIWAVE.EXE will not work in either Windows XP mode, nor VMs such as VMWARE WORKSTATION, nor any of the VMs available in Linux. This is to do with the way the driver for the USB MULTILINK has been architecured.

Making Codewarrior v6.x work in Windows 7 is easy, by patching the installer.
We were not able to get the debugging pod to work to debug live hardware, because of the fact that the USB driver is implemented with Jungo Windriver, and, as per other articles, neither of the virtual machines can push that across into the virtual environment.

I have wasted months trying to solve this, in the end we resurrected old XP licenses and installed XP. However safe to say that, this, combined with Freescale's lack of vision to allow people running Linux to develop for the silicon, forced me into a decision that I will no longer use their products.

However, running multiple instances of the debugger is possible. The maximum seems to be around 20

Comment: that is great news. I don't have a Mac, maybe time to get one.

Comment: Running CW v 6.x in Parallels on OSX. Best decision I ever made.